# Libgdx blender bullet Maximum size of model , object

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics, blender, bullet

Please let me understand the following:

1)Is there any limitations on maximum size of a model (from blender exported to fbx to g3dj) that can be loaded in libgdx.
2)Is There any Limitations on maximum size of an object that bullet physics can handle.

And also can any one please provide on best practices for Models and corresponding physics objects that can be followed to have better efficiancy.

Thank you.

Comment: Size meaning what? File size, size of coordinates, number of vertices, scale? Your last question is too broad.

Comment: By size I mean number of coordinates that make up the bullet body. I apologize , i should have made it clear before.

Answer (score 0):

For physics shapes you should keep your units around `1.0f`. There's no hard maximum for both libgdx and bullet, other than that of the single floating point precision. If you need to use very big models, then consider scaling your units. E.g. use kilometer instead of meter.

The [Bullet manual](https://github.com/erwincoumans/bullet2/blob/master/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf?raw=true) provides very useful information on choosing the correct shape. Have a look at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bullet-Wrapper---Using-models